# "missing" Haproxy sessions in stats page

Tags: haproxy

In my Haproxy config, I have a front-end and several backends. The stats page is showing stats of sessions, CUR = 1098.  (CSV output below)

However, if I add up all the sessions for all its back-ends, I get nowhere close to that number (54).

Am I misunderstanding the meaning of "ssesions - cur" on this page?

Or is http-in front end discarding 95% of incoming sessions because they don't match a backend?  If the latter, I would have though I'd see a bunch of 503s being returned all the time, which I don't.

I thought subsequently perhaps these could be sessions stuck in TCP_WAIT on the client side, but that only accounts for 17% - not 95.

In short, what's happening with these other 95% please?

Many thanks

```
# pxname,bobname,qcur,qmax,scur,smax
http-in,FRONTEND,,,1098,1254
foo_web_zar_and_ws,bob91,0,0,0,1
foo_web_zar_and_ws,bob83,0,0,1,7
foo_web_zar_and_ws,BACKEND,0,0,1,7
foo_web_ned,bob91,0,0,0,0
foo_web_ned,bob83,0,0,0,0
foo_web_ned,BACKEND,0,0,0,0
foo_web_comms,bob91,0,0,0,2
foo_web_comms,bob83,0,0,0,2
foo_web_comms,BACKEND,0,0,0,2
bla_web_comms,bob10,0,0,9,46
bla_web_comms,bob91,0,0,3,32
bla_web_comms,bob83,0,0,3,62
bla_web_comms,BACKEND,0,0,15,85
bla_web_zar_and_ws,bob91,0,0,5,20
bla_web_zar_and_ws,bob83,0,0,7,36
bla_web_zar_and_ws,BACKEND,0,0,12,45
bla_web_ned,bob91,0,0,0,2
bla_web_ned,bob83,0,0,0,2
bla_web_ned,BACKEND,0,0,0,2
stats,FRONTEND,,,1,5
stats,BACKEND,0,0,0,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site is really busy, that could explain that many sessions on the front end.

What comes to mind to me is a possibility that you've got http keepalive turned on for the front end, and there are 1098 connections being kept alive right at that moment, but almost all of them are idle.

Comment: If I'm right about this, it may be a good idea to reduce the keepalive timeout.  Values from 1 to 5 seconds are usually all you really need for keepalive -- reducing the number of total connections required for a single page load is normally what you're after with keepalive, not allowing users to maintain long-term connections.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks. Actually funnily enough, in our case, it's exactly what we want (custom mobile devices that need to keep connections for low latency).

Comment: In that case, you probably want a longer keepalive ... but I think that means you'll see the kind of confusing numbers that you're seeing.

The whole idea is completely a guess, but it fits with my understanding of haproxy.